# In place sub-string reversal in R

Tags: r

I have a string for example, `abcdepzxtru`

I want to reverse only a part of the string and I have the beginning and the ending indices of the substring, say 1 and 5, i.e. I need to reverse `abcde` part of `abcedpzxtru` and the output should be `edcbapzxtru`

I am not sure how to do this in R and googling around is not very helpful.

Comment: Follow the duplicate link to reverse a string and then you're down to just taking a substring using indices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `stringi`...

```
library(stringi)
s <- "abcdepzxtru"

substr(s,1,5) <- stri_reverse(substr(s,1,5))

s
[1] "edcbapzxtru"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sapply(strsplit("abcdepzxtru", ""),
       function(x) paste(x[c(5:1, 6:length(x))], collapse = ""))
#[1] "edcbapzxtru"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
str <- "abcedpzxtru"
init <- 1
end <- 4
paste(c(sapply(end:init, (function(i) substr(str, i, i))), 
      substr(str,(end+1),nchar(str))), collapse = "", sep = "")

# [1] "ecbadpzxtru"
```